# select n-th largest row per group

Tags: r

I am trying to select the n-th largest row per group in a dataset. Example, look at the iris dataset - I found this code on the internet that does this for the second largest value of sepal.length for each type of flower species :

```
library(dplyr)
myfun <-  function(x) {
    u <- unique(x)
    sort(u, decreasing = TRUE)[2L]
}

iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(result = myfun(Sepal.Length))`
```

I am just trying to clarification if I have understand this correctly. If I want 3rd largest, do I just make change like this? How I can select all rows from original data?

```
library(dplyr)
myfun <-  function(x) {
  u <- unique(x)
  sort(u, decreasing = TRUE)[3L]
}

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(result = myfun(Sepal.Length))
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the function to have an extra argument `n` to make it dynamic

```
myfun <-  function(x, n) {
    u <- unique(x)
    sort(u, decreasing = TRUE)[n]
}
```

and then call as

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(result = myfun(Sepal.Length, 3))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Species    result
  <fct>       <dbl>
1 setosa        5.5
2 versicolor    6.8
3 virginica     7.6
```

---

To get all the numeric columns, loop `across` the `numeric` columns

```
iris %>%
   group_by(Species) %>%
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ myfun(.x, 3)))
   # or use nth
   # summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ nth(unique(.x),
   #    order_by = -unique(.x), 3)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 setosa              5.5         4.1          1.6         0.4
2 versicolor          6.8         3.2          4.9         1.6
3 virginica           7.6         3.4          6.6         2.3
```

Comment: thx! can you get all colmns in the output, not just these two?

Comment: so this is 3rd biggest value of sepal.length for each species, correct?

Comment: @ssss3333 yes, it is the 3rd biggest value for Sepal.Length

Answer (score 1):

We could use `nth` from `dplyr` package after grouping and `arrange`:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  arrange(-Sepal.Length, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(across(, ~nth(unique(.x), 3)))
```

```
    Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 setosa              5.5         3.8          1.7         0.3
2 versicolor          6.8         2.8          4.8         1.7
3 virginica           7.6         2.8          6.9         2.3
```

Comment: I was wondering why my result was different, many thanks master!

Comment: thnkx so much! :)